# Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint retrieving old values

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore

I am having a problem with my Virtuoso RDF Store.

Even though I am uploading new RDF files, everytime I make a SPARQL query, the only values which are retrieved are from old RDF files (the ones I manually deleted a long time ago).

This is an example of the SPARQL query I am doing:

```
PREFIX owl-time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#>
PREFIX cdc-owl: <http://www.contextdatacloud.org/ontology/>
SELECT * 
FROM <miOnt:move>
WHERE 
  {
    ?ws rdf:type cdc-owl:WeatherSituation.
    ?ws cdc-owl:hasWeatherTime ?time.
    ?time owl-time:inXSDDateTime "2015-06-16T09:00:00".
    ?ws cdc-owl:hasTemperature ?temperature
  }
```

And these are the results I am obtaining (as it can be seen, they are old files):
[image: SPARQL results]

Any idea of why is this happening?

This is the way my repository looks like:
[image: RDF Repository]

Comment: Ate you loading the new files into new named graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you have loaded your files into the Virtuoso WebDAV (file) repository, but you have not loaded the RDF therein into the Virtuoso (RDF) Quad Store.

See this [guide to the bulk loader](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader), and this [page of RDF loading methods](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert).

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Really helpful. I am not sure what was the way I was uploading the RDF files, but it seems I was not doing it in the correct way. I tried uploading a couple of files to the WebDav and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: is there any possibility of using Apache Jena API in eclipse to upload/update model of triples in Virtuoso?? I read that triples can be inserted, but not sure if it can be done with the Models (I have already created a model of triples with Jena)

Comment: @Havor - Have you read over [the Virtuoso Jena Provider documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider)? If you don't find your answer there, this question is best raised in [Jena-focused](https://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/) and/or [Virtuoso-focused](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) arenas...